# Android RecyclerView.Adapter data change when scroll

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I have set the random color on textview in RecyclerView.Adapter programmatically, but when I scroll top to bottom change color every time how to fix this?

```js
List<String> colors;
colors=new ArrayList<String>();
        colors.add("#f44336");
        colors.add("#4caf50");
        colors.add("#2196f3");
        colors.add("#ff5722");
        colors.add("#673ab7");
        Random r = new Random();
        int i1 = r.nextInt(4- 0) + 0;
        holder.textview.setText(Data.get(position).name.trim());
        holder.textview.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(colors.get(i1)));
```

Comment: save this value in tag and retrieve from tag

Comment: Thanks for your value able answer.But Change only color of the textview, data change problem fixed

Comment: so now it changes the color while scrolling

Comment: yes,now it changes the color while scrolling

Comment: have you achieve your desired output ?

Answer (score 0):

there is many ways to solve this issue, try this:

```
viewHolder.setIsRecyclable(false);
```

Comment: sorry, but this is not worked for me. If you have another solution then plz suggest me. Thank you

Comment: try to make holder final